# Refresh only changed row in ng-table

Tags: angularjs, refresh, ngtable

i am using a ng-table in angularjs and bootstrap. I fill this table with ng-repeat.
Under this table i have a detail where i can change data for the selected row.

My question: Is there a way to refresh only the selected row after refresh?

Or does angularjs allways reload all rows?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can find the row object which you want to update and replace it with new one like

```
$scope.rows = [{},{}];

$scope.rows.splice($scope.rows.indexOf(oldObj),1, objToReplace)
```